# How do you tie UIMA to SOLR Dataimporthandler?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, uima

We've been doing some tests with Apache UIMA. The results are amazing!

Our ideal set up would be a tight integration of UIMA with SOLR. Ideally, we like to pass all the content we index past UIMA, for additional metadata.

There are examples and documentation available how to do the the UIMA integration with the SOLR Update handler, but ideally we'd like to use the existing DataImportHandler (DIH). All our data is imported though a JDBC connection, and should be passed to UIMA before indexing.

Can anybody shed some light on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Import handler do supports the update.processor.
So you can probably tie the dataimport handler with the uima update processor -

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
        <str name="update.processor">uima</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Just an option, haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, we'll give that a try!

Comment: Took a little while to tie it all together, but we got it work with your suggestion. Thanks a lot!